# Excel VBA : Copy SQL Table with Heading (Column name)

Tags: vba, excel

I need to insert column name for this data but result that I get only data without column name. Is there anything wrong with my codes?
Thank you.

```
Private Sub pbTRPOS_Click()

    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim sSQLQry As String
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
    Dim DirFile As String
    Dim i As Long

    DirFile = "C:\Work\TRPOS.txt"

    If Len(Dir(DirFile)) <> 0 Then
        SetAttr DirFile, vbNormal
        Kill DirFile
    End If

    DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    sconnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=DWSQL\BCAPP;Database=MVS;Uid=mvs;Pwd=mvs;"
    Conn.Open sconnect

    sSQLSting = "SELECT * FROM [MVS].[dbo].[TRPOS] where pos_no = '" & Sheets("Get Text File").Cells(5, 3) & "'"

    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Work\TRPOS.csv", FileFormat:=6

    For i = 0 To mrs.Fields.Count - 1
        Sheets("TRPOS").Cells(1, i + 1).Value = mrs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

    mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn

    Sheets("TRPOS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs
    mrs.Close
    Conn.Close

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    Name "C:\Work\TRPOS.csv" As "C:\Work\TRPOS.txt"

End Sub
```

Comment: `Recordset` doesn't offer a native way of getting the column names *with* the data. You need to loop over the columns and collect the names into an array, then insert that array where you want the headers, and insert the data 1 row below that.

Comment: Any example for loop array through SQL? Thank you @ThunderFrame

Comment: You're trying to write the field names before opening the Recordset.  Open the Recordset and *then* write the field names.